# Hiding the status bar on all pages in a Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, statusbar

I can hide the status bar on each page but is there an easier way to do this in one place?

Answer (score 2):

Go in you App.xaml.cs file and in the `OnLaunched` add
this

```
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

// Hide the status bar
await statusBar.HideAsync();
```

Comment: Yes indeed this works, but then you need to add "async" to OnLaunched.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it in the App.xaml.cs in the `OnLaunched` event handler. In order to avoid adding `async` to the `OnLaunched` method, you can use `Wait()` method of `Task`:

```
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

// Hide the status bar
Task hidingStatusBarTask = statusBar.HideAsync();
hidingStatusBarTask.Wait();
```

Comment: Yes but you can't convert 'IAsyncAction' to 'Task' and if i do a cast like this "(Task)statusBar.HideAsync" the app crashes.